# year function in Scala Spark returning wrong year

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to extract the year value from the date in Scala using year function, but it is returning 1 year less than the actual value:

```
val df = Seq(
  ("1000-01-03 00:00:00")
).toDF("date_val")
.withColumn("conv_date", to_date(col("date_val")))
.withColumn("year_val", year(to_date(col("date_val"))))
.withColumn("year_val_trunc", trunc( to_date(col("date_val")),"year"))
df
.show()
```

Gives the output:

```
+-------------------+----------+--------+--------------+
|           date_val| conv_date|year_val|year_val_trunc|
+-------------------+----------+--------+--------------+
|1000-01-03 00:00:00|1000-01-03|     999|    0999-01-06|
+-------------------+----------+--------+--------------+
```

Strange part is that when I replace the date with anything greater than 1000-01-05, it works as expected, i.e, giver the year_val as 1000. Am I missing something here?

Comment: This is majorly interesting and might be a bug in spark itself. It starts happening bellow date `1500-1-1 00:00:00` including it. `1500-1-2 00:00:00` and up is fine.

Comment: Actually all years > 1400 works

Comment: I tested it locally. Here is me backing my previous comment. `scala> res2.show
+-------------------+----+----------+
|               date|year|year_trunc|
+-------------------+----+----------+
|1500-01-02 00:00:00|1500|1500-01-02|
|1500-01-01 00:00:00|1499|1499-01-02|`

Comment: does look buggy, i would lodge a JIRA